# Replace Values on condition

Tags: r, dataframe

I'm trying to replace values like shown here in this table.

- If `A` is `NA` and also `B` and `C` set `A` to `Unknown`.
- If `A` is `NA` and `B` or `C` has got a Value, set `A` to `Missing Value`

---

```
     A         B     C   
 1  NA        NA    NA  
 2  NA       200    NA  


              A        B       C       
1  NotImportant       NA      NA   
2       Unknown      200      NA
```

I tried some kind of,

```
if(is.na(ColumnA)) ColumnB[is.na(ColumnB)] <= "Not Important"  
if(is.na(ColumnA)) ColumnB[!is.na(ColumnB)] <= "Unknown"
```

but I get no result.

Could somebody help me out with this? I hope I described my problem well.

Answer (score 1):

```
df$A <- ifelse(!is.na(df$A), 
                      df$A, 
                      ifelse(is.na(df$B) & is.na(df$C), 
                             "Not Important", 
                             "Missing Value"))

# A   B  C
# 1 Not Important  NA NA
# 2 Missing Value 200 NA
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this where `df` is your data:

```
df[rowSums(is.na(df))==3,]$A <- "NotImportant"
df[with(df, is.na(A) & (!is.na(B) | !is.na(C))),]$A <- "Unknown"

#             A   B  C
#1 NotImportant  NA NA
#2      Unknown 200 NA
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to do that using `case_when` from `dplyr`:

```
df <- structure(list(A = c(NA, NA), B = c(NA, 200L), C = c(NA, NA)), .Names = c("A",
"B", "C"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", "2"))

library(dplyr)
df%>%
mutate(A=case_when(
 is.na(.$A)&is.na(.$B)&is.na(.$C)   ~ "Not Important",
 is.na(.$A)&(is.na(.$B)|is.na(.$C)) ~ "Unknown")
 )

              A   B  C
1 Not Important  NA NA
2       Unknown 200 NA
```